# what does @ means before include or require

Tags: php, operators, error-suppression

i wonder what does @ means when we use it before include or require in php ?!

such as :

```
@include('block.php');
```

maybe its a noob question , but i need to know it guys ?!

so sorry for that

Comment: see e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1032161/what-is-the-use-of-symbol-in-php and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/138159/php-alias-function

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`@` is the shut-up operator. If something goes wrong, no error message will be shown. It's usually a bad practice to use it; first because error messages happen for a good reason, and second because it's ridiculously slow for what it does.

It's roughly equivalent to wrapping the statement in:

```
$oldErrorLevel = error_reporting(0);
// the statement
error_reporting($oldErrorLevel);
```

[Here's the link to the PHP manual page documenting it.](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.errorcontrol.php)

Comment: i think ur answer is more complete and to the point , actually i guessed that but i was not sure , thanks

Answer (score 3):

@ before a function call suppresses any errors that function would normally output.

In the case of `include`, the person doing that wants the script to keep going if `block.php` isn't present. A better way of doing this is usually to do something like this instead:

```
if(is_readable('block.php')) {
  include('block.php');
}
```

Comment: There are other reasons that can prevent a file from loading though, like permissions.

Answer (score 0):

@ is the error supression operator in php, you won't see any error if the file is not found in that statement.